# How can exception if mono is empty?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor, r2dbc

I use webflux and r2dbc.
If there is a duplicate value in DB, I want to throw an error.

```
Handler.java
Mono<ServerResponse> save(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(User.class)
            .flatMap(user-> userService.save(user))
            .flatMap(user -> ok().build());
    }
```

```
userService.java
public Mono<User> save(User user) { 
    userRepository.find(user.getId()); // if Mono<User> is empty throw BadRequest Exception
    return userRepository.save(todo);
}
```

```
Router.java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<?> routes(Handler handler) {
    return route(POST("/save"), handler::save);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
userRepository.find(user.getId())
              .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadRequestException()));
```

Comment: you need to chain on the save method or this will never get called.